# If column matches, print lines in both files

Tags: awk

I have two tab delim files

file1

```
LOC100224866    1       325001  0.133977
LOC105758527    1       75001   0.252737
LOC100218126    1       85001   0.174872
LOC105758529    1       125001  0.02342
NRF1    1       175001  0.257585
UBE2H   1       225001  0.303165
KLHDC10 1       275001  0.22267
TMEM209 1       295001  0.273941
CPA2    1       315001  0.181312
CEP41   1       345001  0.248943
```

and

file2

```
 0.265838 CLIC6
 0.390470 NRF1
 0.126332 UBE2H
 0.236400 LOC100224866
 0.181189 DOPEY2
 0.288050 MORC3
 0.182429 CHAF1B
 0.220355 SIM2
 0.106513 HLCS
 0.177958 DSCR3
```

I wanna match col1 file1 to col2 file2, and add those matching lines of file1 as new columns in file2, thus preserving the order of entries in file2.

so that the output would be

```
 0.390470 NRF1     NRF1    1       175001  0.257585
 0.126332 UBE2H    UBE2H   1       225001  0.303165
 0.236400 LOC100224866    LOC100224866    1       325001  0.133977
```

I've tried several strategies from similar posts but all of them are failing.
Have tried for example,

```
awk -F$"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} ($2 in a) {print $1, $2, a[$1] }' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're looking the wrong key from file1.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$0}' file2 file1

0.390470 NRF1    1       175001  0.257585
0.126332 UBE2H   1       225001  0.303165
0.236400 LOC100224866    1       325001  0.133977
```

the key needs to match, there is no need to print it again, if you want to duplicate do `print a[$1],$1,$0` instead.

Comment: Got it! Thxs. but it is still adding file2 to file1. I guess need the opposite so the order kept is from file2. I tried awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4; next} $2 in a {print a[$1],$0}' singlepos_genes_fst.annot.toplot bamgenes.fst but didint work. I scrambled the example a bit to clarify the question.